# Limit number of character of capturing group

Tags: regex

Let's say i have this text : `"AAAA1 AAA11 AA111AA A1111 AAAAA AAAA1111"`.

I want to find all occurrences matching these 3 criteria :
 -Capital letter 1 to 4 times
 -Digit 1 to 4 times
 -Max number of characters to be 5

so the matches would be :
`{"AAAA1", "AAA11", "AA111", "A1111", "AAAA1"}`

i tried

```
([A-Z]{1,4}[0-9]{1,4}){5}
```

but i knew it would fail, since it's looking for five time my group.

Is there a way to limit result of the groups to 5 characters?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can limit the character count with a look ahead while checking the pattern with you matching part.

If you can split the input by whitespace you can use:

```
^(?=.{2,5}$)[A-Z]{1,4}[0-9]{1,4}$
```

See [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/hQ8qI6/46).

If you cannot split by whitespace you can use capturing group with `(?:^| )(?=.{2,5}(?=$| ))([A-Z]{1,4}[0-9]{1,4})(?=$| )` for example, or lookbehind or `\K` to do the split depending on your regex flavor (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hQ8qI6/47)).

---

**PREVIOUS ANSWER**, wrongly matches `A1A1A`, updated after @a_guest remark.

You can use a lookahead to check for your pattern, while limiting the character count with the matching part of the regex:

```
(?=[A-Z]{1,4}[0-9]{1,4}).{2,5}
```

See [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/hQ8qI6/1).

Comment: This matches for example `A1A1A` as well (because the look ahead distance is smaller than the matching distance) which seems to be undesired according to the OP (considering examples + description). Instead it seems the regex should match a sequence of letters *followed* by a sequence of digits (but not intermingled with), each sequence having length `1-4` and the overall combination having max. length `5`.

Comment: thanks @a_guest, I updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. It works!