# Correct syntax for regex to limit total length of matched group

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make a regex for matching name which can have more than one words.
But at the same time I want to limit the total length to 20.

I used `/\b(\w+ (\s\w+)*){1,20}\b/` .

I am getting the syntax but it is not checking word length constraint. Why?

Note: I am writing code in Javascript.

Comment: You are repeating the *entire* "names" block up to 20 times.

Comment: is it that you want the entire match to be a maximum of 20 chars? or do you want the length of each individual group to be a maximum of 20?

Comment: Posting some examples of inputs and their expected outputs could help

Comment: I want entire match to be a maximum of 20 chars.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit this is not the way to solve problem you are literally saying if you can't drive then take a cab.

Comment: @DeepakYadav I can't see what you are responding to.

Comment: @DeepakYadav Oh I remember now, I deleted a comment a few days ago - it was something along the lines of "not everything needs to be solved by a regex" and I said that because I thought maybe this problem _should not_ be solved by a regex. That's not the same thing as your analogy at all.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit leave I was frustrated that time because my regex was not working...I am sorry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
var test = [
    "abc123 def456 ghi789",
    "123456789012345678901",
    "123456",
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a+' :'+/^(?=.{1,20}$)\w+(?: \w+)*$/.test(a);
}));
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                   : beginning of line
    (?=.{1,20}$)    : positive lookahead, make sure we have no more than 20 characters
    \w+             : 1 or more word character
    (?: \w+)*       : a space followed by 1 or more word char, may appear 0 or more times
$
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Limit number of character of capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29283628/limit-number-of-character-of-capturing-group)

This will still match, but limit at 20. (It took a few edits, but I think it got it...)

```js
let rx = /(?=\b(\w+(\s\w+)*)\b).{1,20}/

let m = rx.exec('one two three four')
console.log(m[0])
console.log(m[0].length)

m = rx.exec('one two three four five six seven eight')
console.log(m[0])
console.log(m[0].length)

m = rx.exec('wwwww wwwww wwwww wwwww wwwww')
console.log(m[0])
console.log(m[0].length)
```

Comment: They want the **total** length to be less or equal to 20.

Comment: This is not working like it is just checking the constraint of last word if it is less than 20 it is allowing any string "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww www" is also working. Plus i want length of whole string less than 20.

Comment: @DeepakYadav please confirm this works as expected.  Thanks.

Comment: @StevenSpungin:It is working :) thanks also i used accidently different regex whixh seems to be working as well but i don't have the explaination why it is working:( I used   /(\b(\w(\s\w+)*)\b){1,20}/

Answer (score -2):

Slight modification - try this (the {1, 20} is on the outside [here](https://regex101.com/r/9kySrI/1):

```
(\b(\w+ (\s\w+)*)\b){1,20}
```

Comment: They want the **total** length to be less or equal to 20.

Comment: It is working :) Is there any way to not let user enter name with space at the end like "deepak "should not be allowed.

Comment: @DeepakYadav: No, it is not working, it matches `abcdefghi qsjhfjsqh  fsjkhffjhg  `

Comment: @Toto : Right it is not working but I accidently used wrong regex which is working but now I don't know why it is working:(  I used /(\b(\w(\s\w+)*)\b){1,20}/